# Why does the vector returned by my C++ function contain garbage values in the caller?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, folly

I've created a simple C++ program to read and tokenize input from cin. However, while the tokens in my helper function are correct, the tokens in the caller function (main) are garbage values.

As an example, if I enter "a b c" as the input, the vector of tokens in my helper function (get_input_tokens) contains "a", "b", "c", but the vector of tokens in main contains "?", "?", "".

My understanding is that the vector should be returned by value to the caller, so a new copy of the vector should be created in the caller (main) that is identical to the original vector. Would anyone be able to give me some ideas about why this is happening?

```
#include <folly/String.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<folly::StringPiece> get_input_tokens() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);   // Enter in "a b c"
    
    vector<folly::StringPiece> tokensVec;
    folly::split(" ", input, tokensVec);

    // Print tokensVec - prints out "a", "b", "c"
    for (int i=0; i<tokensVec.size(); i++) {
        cout << tokensVec[i] << endl;
    }

    return tokensVec;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto tokensVec = get_input_tokens();

    // Print tokensVec - prints out "?", "?", ""
    for (int i=0; i<tokensVec.size(); i++) {
        cout << tokensVec[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reference for folly::split: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/String.h#L403.

Comment: What is `folly::split`? It seems the most relevant function of creating vector. Please add it into your question.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of the folly/String with us? To my knowledge compilers decide how to return it and move constructor or copy constructor can be either used to do this task. So problem is probably with either copy or move constructor of the folly/String class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Ah, sorry, forgot to add that - it's a library function from folly (Facebook's open-source C++ library) that does the same thing as Python's split function (i.e. split an input string on a delimiter). Reference: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/String.h#L403.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sure, here is the implementation: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/String.h#L403.

I see, that makes sense - let me take a look at the move and copy constructors for folly::StringPiece in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a `StringPiece` holds pointers into the string it is a piece of.
In your case, that's `input`, which is destroyed when the function returns and makes all the `StringPiece`s invalid.

You need a different type for the tokens.
I'm not familiar with folly, but if the creators haven't lost the plot completely, `std::string` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't know StringPiece held pointers into another string - it makes sense that if it's pointing to a local variable then it would be invalid outside of that variable's scope.

I tried with std::string, but am getting these errors:
`
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "folly::makeConversionError(folly::ConversionCode, folly::Range<char const*>)", referenced from:
      std::__1::enable_if<!(std::is_same<folly::Range<char const*>, std::__1::basic_string`

But I will create a new question for that, as that is a different issue.